# HBase concurrent put/insert to same row key but different column

Tags: hbase

I have been reading up on Hbase concurrency but does not know how it will work.  I am reading different text files in many mappers and put/insert into Hbase table with different qualifier/column for the same row key.
So basically one mapper will write to rowkey1 with qualifier1 & another mapper will write to rowkey1 with qualifier2.  Would i get at the end rowkey1 with qualifier1 & qualifier2. ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes independent qualifiers are independent cells or storage locations in HBase.